# Upload video to facebook error: Video Upload Time Out

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried upload video to Facebook using Graph API and got this error.

```
code = 390;
error_subcode = 1363030;
error_user_msg = "Your video upload timed out before it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large. Please try again.";
 error_user_title = "Video Upload Time Out";
 message = "There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again.";
```

Below is my code:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:videoURL];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                videoData, @"video.mp4",
                                @"video/mp4", @"contentType",
                                @"message text", @"title",
                                @"title text", @"description",
                                nil];
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                  initWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                  parameters: params
                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {
                         NSLog(@"Post id:%@", result[@"id"]);
                     }
                     else {
                         NSLog(@"video upload error: %@", error.description);
                     }
                 }];
```

I read questions and answers and I can not found correct solution.
I don't think it is network or video codec issue.
The video file size is below 1MB and it is uploaded without any problem in Facebook app.

What is the issue? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey did you find solution of this issue? I also got this while using Distribution profile but it was working with Developer profile. Weird.

Comment: are you solved this error??? i am getting same error..